# Can't return a temporary object from function

Tags: c++

In the header file:

```
class Point{
    public:
        Point();    // constructor
        Point(double x, double y);  // constructor
        Point(Point& A);    //Copy Constructor
        ~Point();   // destructor

        // below are the operator declarations. 
        Point operator - () const; // Negate the coordinates.

    private:
        double xCord;
        double yCord;

};
```

In the Cpp implementation file, related constructor:

```
Point::Point(double x, double y){   // constructor
    X(x);// void X(double x) is a function to set the xCord 
    Y(y);// so is Y(y)

}

Point Point::operator-() const{ // Negate the coordinates.
    Point temp(-xCord,-yCord);
    return temp;
    // return Point(-xCord,-yCord); // cannot use this one
}
```

It seems that I cannot put a constructor in the return line. It's OK to build one in the code, but if I put it in the return, it will give the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Point::Point(Point)’

and then the compiler lists all the constructors which I have. But hey, it obviously takes two double arguments, not a Point class. So why is that?

Also I noticed, in sample code given by professor, they were fine:

```
Complex::Complex(double dx, double dy)
{
    x = dx;
    y = dy;
}

Complex Complex::operator - () const
{ 
    return Complex(- x, - y);
}
```

Comment: Your copy constructor doesn't allow temporaries to be copied.

Comment: `Point(Point& A);    //Copy Constructor` isn't _really_ a useful copy constructor. You need `Point(const Point& A);` since you can't copy from temporary instances.

Comment: `Point::Point(double x, double y){   // constructor
    X(x);
    Y(y);` Use the initialization list

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, your code contains a few other errors unrelated to your question. You can avoid these errors by copy pasting code directly from your editor (verifying before that it compiles / produces the expected compile error)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh yes the problem fixed after I change the copy constructor to the  way you gave me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this statement

```
// return Point(-xCord,-yCord); // cannot use this one
```

is that there is created a temporary object. Temporary objects may not be changed so functions that use them as arguments have to declare the corresponding parameter as constant reference instead of non-const reference.

Declare the copy constructor the following way

```
Point( const Point& A );    //Copy Constructor
```

or as

```
Point( const Point& A ) = default;    //Copy Constructor
```

The other approach is to add a move constructor to your class without changing the copy constructor. For example

```
class Point{
    public:
        Point();    // constructor
        Point(double x, double y);  // constructor
        Point( Point& A);    //Copy Constructor
        Point( Point &&A ); // Move Constructor
```

In this case in statement

```
return Point(-xCord,-yCord);
```

the compiler will use the move constructor.

Comment: In this case, don't declare it at all. The implicit one will do the right thing.

Comment: @Mike Seymour For the documentation purpose there is a sense to define it as default if the class has already other explicit constructor declarations.

Comment: Nobody mentioned this yet, but the reason the code is failing is that the *returned value* is a separate thing to any objects within the function; it is copy-constructed from whatever thing you `return`.  In the first case your copy-constructor matches; however in the second case your copy-constructor does not match (the temporary object cannot bind to the non-const reference), so the returned value cannot be created.  (It is nothing to do with how `operator-` is invoked).

Comment: Often this *returned value* is elided by the compiler (even if the copy-constructor had side effects), however the language rules say that the copy-constructor must be well-formed and accessible even if it is elided.

Answer (score 7):

```
Point::Point(double x, double y){   // constructor
    X(x);
    Y(y);
}
```

Is this verbatim code or paraphrased? Because as it stands, it is complete nonsense. Fix:

```
Point::Point(double x, double y) : xCord(x), yCord(y)
{
}
```

Also, you don't need to define the copy constructor manually, because the compiler will provide one for you (with the correct signature) that does exactly what you want: copy the data members.

Comment: I paraphrased and only put the related code in the post. I will add more code. and I tried your code but met the same problem. Also I used that copy constructor just because my TA said that's mandatory. Thanks anyway and I learnt the colon syntax :)